# Deserialize JSON list with a name parameter

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am able to deserialize a list in the below format

```
[{"id":5,"somevalue":"x","somevalue":"y"},{},{} .....]
```

using

```
var response = MyJsonResponse;
response.Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TDecode>>(response.ResponseResult);
```

But, I am unable to Deserialize a list with a name ex:

```
{"results": [{"id":5,"somevalue":"x","somevalue":"y"},{},{} .....]}
```

How would you de-serialize an object like that?

Comment: You need a wrapper class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable because you have to create another object wrapping your list:

```
public RootObj
{
    public List<TDecode> results { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize it

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(response.ResponseResult);
```

Another option is to deserialize as `dynamic` and then to case the `result.results` to a `List<TDecode>`.